# SUMIF with multi sheets and the same value

Tags: excel, exception, nullpointerexception, excel-formula, vba

I'm using this:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A223,”Lenovo_Core_I5″,B2:B222)-SUMIF(A2:A223,”Lenovo_Core_I5″,C2:C222)
```

and it works on the same sheet. However, I use multi sheets, so I try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(New_Order!B1:B94),INDIRECT(New_Order!A1:A94),”Lenovo_Core_I7″))-SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(New_Applying!C7:C32),INDIRECT(New_Applying!A7:A32),”Lenovo_Core_I7″))
```

but it's showing `#REF!` error.

Please see below:

[image]

Comment: Better use `Named Range`.

Comment: The formulas included in your question are not the one giving the error in your screendump - the one giving an error starts off with `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(""&New_Order!&"'!B2:` - that is definitely going to give problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without using `INDIRECT` FUNCTION

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(New_Order!B1:B94,New_Order!A1:A94,”Lenovo_Core_I7″)) - 
SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(New_Applying!C7:C32,New_Applying!A7:A32,”Lenovo_Core_I7″))
```

Read more about referencing values from other sheets [Here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/08/excel-reference-another-sheet-workbook/)

Comment: It's showing #NAME?
Anyway I solved it , I'm using this
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF((Order!$A$5:$A$222),"INK",(Order!$B$5:$B$222)))-SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF((Applying!$A$5:$A$222),"INK",(Applying!$C$5:$C$222)))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need INDIRECT nor SUMPRODUCT. Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(New_Order!B1:B94,New_Order!A1:A94,”Lenovo_Core_I7″) - 
SUMIFS(New_Applying!C7:C32,New_Applying!A7:A32,”Lenovo_Core_I7″)
```

Comment: I'm using this and it's working well
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF((Order!$A$5:$A$222),"INK",(Order!$B$5:$B$222)))-SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF((Applying!$A$5:$A$222),"INK",(Applying!$C$5:$C$222)))

Comment: Yes, but in this case sumproduct does add any value.